# Do oral vaccines exist?

Tags: medicine, vaccination

Do edible vaccines exist, and if yes, what is their mode of action? Are there any edible vaccines commercially available now?

Answer (score 4):

In short, yes.

A good example of an orally-administered vaccine is this [Polio vaccine](http://www.polioeradication.org/Polioandprevention/Thevaccines/Oralpoliovaccine%28OPV%29.aspx).

Comment: Other than polio..?? Have anyone heard about that vaccine that are incorporated into food items like potato or banana?

Comment: Rabies, typhoid and many others are available as oral formulations. @Ashwin.N You are asking about a GM Food with vaccine properties?

Comment: Yes sir!! You are right!! I was asking about that only!! Can you tell me more about GM food with vaccine properties with real life examples!! Plz

Comment: Ah. My mistake. Yes, those exist. I am not aware of any large-scale deployments, but there have certainly been trials.

Examples: Hepatitis B vaccine trial in transgenic potatoes: http://www.pnas.org/content/102/9/3378.short

E. coli vaccine, also in potatoes (mouse trial): http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264410X98800200

Comment: @Ashwin.N In that case can you edit your question to add this information?